# Como puedo llenar tres Array e imprimir el contenido

Tags: c++17

Teniendo el siguiente enunciado:

*"Una empresa dedicada al transporte de mercancía cobra el envío de paquetes de acuerdo con su peso en gramos y sabiendo que el valor base del envío es de $250 por gramo:*

- *Si el peso del paquete es inferior a 75 gramos el costo de su envío
  tiene un descuento del 2,5% sobre el valor base.*
- *Si el peso está entre 75 y 500 gramos el costo del envío es el valor
  base.*
- *Si el peso es superior a 500 gramos el costo tendrá un incremento del
  7.5% sobre el valor base.*

*Diseñe un programa que permita registrar X envíos, utilizando 2 arreglos: El arreglo1 que almacene el peso del paquete y el arreglo2 donde se calcule el costo del envío de cada uno de ellos. Imprimir los 2 arreglos."*

Para resolver el enunciado he llegado al siguiente código en c++:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char sigue = 'S';
    while (sigue == 'S')
    {
        int envio[] = {0};
        float peso[] = {0};
        float costo[] = {0};
        float precioBase = 250;
        
        for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
            envio[x] = envio[x] + 1;
            cout << "Para el Envio, Por favor Ingrese el Peso del Paquete en Gramos: ";
            cin >> peso[x];
            if(peso[x] < 75){
                costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase) - (peso[x] * ((precioBase / 100) * 2.5));
            }
            if(peso[x] >= 75 && peso[x] <= 500){
                costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase);
            }
        
            if(peso[x] > 500){
                costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase) + (peso[x] * ((precioBase / 100) * 7.5));
            }
            cout << "El Precio Total del Envio es: $" << costo[x] << endl;
        }
        sigue = ' ';
        cout << "¿Desea Ingresar un Nuevo Envio? S/N : ";
        cin >> sigue;
        sigue = toupper(sigue);
    }
}
```

Hasta este punto puedo hacer que me permita ingresar varios valores de peso en gramos por envio, y me da el costo teniendo en cuenta las opciones dadas por el enunciado, esto sucede cada que le digo que deseo ingresar un nuevo envió. Pero al indicarle que no deseo ingresar un nuevo envio debería mostrarme una salida como la siguiente:

```
El Envió No. 1 con un Peso de: 100 gramos. Tiene un Costo de: $2500
El Envió No. 2 con un Peso de: 10 gramos. Tiene un Costo de: $2437.5
El Envió No. 3 con un Peso de: 1000 gramos. Tiene un Costo de: $268750
```

Intente lograr que me imprimiera esa salida con el siguiente codigo:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
        cout << "El Envio No. " << envio[x];
        for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
            cout << " con un Peso de: " << peso[x] << " gramos. ";
            for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
                cout << " Tiene un Costo de: $" << peso[x];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Pero me saca un error y no me deja continuar. He intentado de varias maneras pero la verdad hasta ahora empiezo con c++ y no logro hallar algo similar que me permita guiarme a completar este ejercicio.

El código completo del programa que he logrado hasta ahora es este:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char sigue = 'S';
    while (sigue == 'S')
    {
        int envio[] = {0};
        float peso[] = {0};
        float costo[] = {0};
        float precioBase = 250;
        
        for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
            envio[x] = envio[x] + 1;
            cout << "Para el Envio, Por favor Ingrese el Peso del Paquete en Gramos: ";
            cin >> peso[x];
            if(peso[x] < 75){
                costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase) - (peso[x] * ((precioBase / 100) * 2.5));
            }
            if(peso[x] >= 75 && peso[x] <= 500){
                costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase);
            }
        
            if(peso[x] > 500){
                costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase) + (peso[x] * ((precioBase / 100) * 7.5));
            }
            cout << "El Precio Total del Envio es: $" << costo[x] << endl;
        }
        sigue = ' ';
        cout << "¿Desea Ingresar un Nuevo Envio? S/N : ";
        cin >> sigue;
        sigue = toupper(sigue);
    }
    
    for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
        cout << "El Envio No. " << envio[x];
        for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
            cout << " con un Peso de: " << peso[x] << " gramos. ";
            for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
                cout << " Tiene un Costo de: $" << peso[x];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Podrian por favor ayudarme a resolver lo que me falta para que vaya llenándose cada array correctamente y al final poder imprimir la salida como la necesito. Les agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola he notado que tiene varios problemas en el algoritmo.

El primero es donde creas los arrays:

```
    int envio[] = {0};
    float peso[] = {0};
    float costo[] = {0};
    float precioBase = 250;
```

El problema es que estas reservando espacio solo para un elemento, necesitas especificar entre corchetes la cantidad de valores a guardar, ejemplo para 10:

```
    int envio[10];
    float peso[10];
    float costo[10];
    float precioBase = 250;
```

Podemos pedirle al usuario la cantidad de envíos a realizar y así obtener la cantidad de valores que los arrays tendrán:

```
    int cantidad;
    cout << "Cantidad de envios: ";
    cin >> cantidad;

    int envio[cantidad];
    float peso[cantidad];
    float costo[cantidad];
    float precioBase = 250;
```

Otro error que cometes es utilizar un bucle for, tanto para el ingreso de datos como al imprimir estos, estos bucles solo iteran una vez lo cual es lo mismo tener el código fuera de estos:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
```

Ahora como hemos pedido la cantidad de envíos podemos hacer el bucle que itere desde 0 hasta la cantidad de envíos, además podemos eliminar el array **envió** ya que este solo sirve para saber el número del envió, lo podemos reemplazar con la variable del bucle.

Por lo cual tenemos:

```
    int cantidad;
    cout << "Cantidad de envios: ";
    cin >> cantidad;

    float peso[cantidad];
    float costo[cantidad];
    float precioBase = 250;

    for (int x = 0; x < cantidad; x++) {
        cout << "Para el Envio, Por favor Ingrese el Peso del Paquete en Gramos: ";

        cin >> peso[x];

        if(peso[x] < 75){
            costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase) - (peso[x] * ((precioBase / 100) * 2.5));
        }

        else if(peso[x] >= 75 && peso[x] <= 500){
            costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase);
        }
    
        else if(peso[x] > 500){
            costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase) + (peso[x] * ((precioBase / 100) * 7.5));
        }

        cout << "El Precio Total del Envio es: $" << costo[x] << endl;
    }
```

Para mostrar la lista en la última parte como quieres, cometes el mismo error de iterar solo una vez, además arroja un error ya que estas declarando la variable x dos veces para un bucle anidado, este bucle también solo se ejecutaría una vez:

Antes pedimos la cantidad de envíos lo cual podemos utilizar este número para el bucle y mostrar los valores del array:

**Eliminamos el bucle while ya que este se puede ejecutar indefinidas veces, ejemplo si inicializamos los arrays para 10 elementos pero el usuario ingresa 13, no hay espacio para guardar 3 registros más.**

Código final:

```
    int cantidad;
    cout << "Cantidad de envios: ";
    cin >> cantidad;

    float peso[cantidad];
    float costo[cantidad];
    float precioBase = 250;

    for (int x = 0; x < cantidad; x++) {
        cout << "Para el Envio, Por favor Ingrese el Peso del Paquete en Gramos: ";

        cin >> peso[x];

        if(peso[x] < 75){
            costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase) - (peso[x] * ((precioBase / 100) * 2.5));
        }

        else if(peso[x] >= 75 && peso[x] <= 500){
            costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase);
        }
    
        else if(peso[x] > 500){
            costo[x] = (peso[x] * precioBase) + (peso[x] * ((precioBase / 100) * 7.5));
        }

        cout << "El Precio Total del Envio es: $" << costo[x] << endl;
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < cantidad; x++){
           cout << "El Envio No. " << x + 1 << " con un Peso de: " << peso[x] << " gramos. Tiene un Costo de: $" << costo[x] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Carlos Eduardo, tu respuesta me ayudo mucho a comprender mejor en que estaba fallando y de paso me ayudaste a ahorrar unas cuantas líneas de código. Muchas gracias.